# Vb.net multiple textbox events change

Tags: vb.net, object, events, textbox, tooltip

How can I change the mausehover event of all TextBox

```
Private Sub TextBox1_MouseHover(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseHover
    ToolTip1.SetToolTip(TextBox1, TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox2_MouseHover(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.MouseHover
    ToolTip1.SetToolTip(TextBox2, TextBo2.Text)
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox3_MouseHover(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.MouseHover
    ToolTip1.SetToolTip(TextBox3, TextBox3.Text)
End Sub
```

How can I add code to the all textbox mousehover event in the shortest way
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry your question is confusing could you please add more details of your problem.. Thanks

Comment: How can I add code to the all textbox mousehover event in the shortest way

Comment: That is already the shortest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it :

```
Private Sub TextBox_MouseHover(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseHover, TextBox2.MouseHover, TextBox3.MouseHover
    Dim tbx = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
    ToolTip1.SetToolTip(tbx, tbx.Text)
End Sub
```